# Collecting Stats

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, statistics, mac-app-store

I'm writing an application for the Mac App Store in Obj-C/Cocoa. The app processes .html files and does not require an internet connection.

I was wondering, what would be the best way to collect statistics? All I'm interested in is the number of files processed.

That way, on the app's home page, I can display XXX,XXX files processed.

I was thinking that I would just post to a web server whenever a file was converted, but that would considerably slow down the app and wouldn't work if the user was not connected to the internet.

Comment: http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html

Comment: @Feo it only supports Java, Blackberry, Android, iPhone, Windows Phone, and iPad. :(

Comment: it supports any device with internet.

Comment: @Feo When I go to Applications -> Create A New Application, it brings me to a Select Platform page where I have to select Java, Blackberry, Android, iPhone, Windows Phone, or iPad. What would I select?

Comment: @Feo Flurry relies on UIKit, so it wouldn't compile on a Mac.

Comment: Why would that slow down the app? Just make a request saying X amount of files were processed.

Comment: @KenAspeslagh doing what you said wouldn't really slow it down. I was saying that if I make a post every time a file is processed (1 post per file) it could get laggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accumulate the stats internally to be uploaded only every so often (each day, perhaps). You'd save the accumulated number across restarts using `NSUserDefaults`.

You should ask the user for permission to upload data, even something so seemingly innocuous as a count of processed files.

You'd use a simple HTTP request to upload the data.  (You know it will be vulnerable to spoofing, right?)  You should use the [network reachability API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html) to check whether the system is network connected before trying, so you don't force a dial-up, for example.  The reachability API can't tell you that your connection will for sure succeed, so you should handle failure to connect gracefully.